# Is it possible to have more than one active artifact in Redemption?

Tags: redemption-tcg

I have tried to look on the official Redemption REGEX and site, and have googled but can't seem to find a clarification to this question.

My brother and I got into Redemption recently. There aren't as many player groups around in our area anymore so it becomes difficult to ask rules questions.

What I am curious about is if it is possible (and legal) to have more than one active artifact in play?

Here are the specific scenarios I am curious about:
The Solomon's Temple fortress (and its equivalents like Zerubbabel's Temple, The Tabernacle, etc.). Since the artifact moves from your pile to your fortress, does this mean you can turn up a second artifact (not on the same turn though)? So there is one active in the Temple and one active on the artifact pile?

And what about the Priestly Breastpiece? Since that can be attached to a high priest, does that mean that another artifact can be activated? (For that matter is it possible to have three artifacts, one on the artifact pile, one in a Temple, and one assigned to a Priest?)

Just wondering what the ruling is out there and if there is clear documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you may have two Artifacts active.**

[Solomon's Temple's](http://redemption.wikia.com/wiki/Solomon%E2%80%99s_Temple_%28Pa%29) rules text seems pretty clear on the matter:

> Holder may activate a second Artifact from Artifact pile or hand on this Fortress if that Artifact was found in Solomon's Temple. Artifact takes immediate effect.

The [rules](http://www.cactusgamedesign.com/downloads/rulebook_10th_anniversary.pdf) for **Artifact Activation** only prevent one artifact from being active on the **artifact pile**.

> **Artifact Activation:** Only one artifact in the artifact pile may be active at a time. Once per turn, you may select one artifact to be activated and flip it face up on your artifact pile.